# Чем атомарные операции записи и чтения отличаются от операции load/store?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, atomic, lock-free

Чем атомарные операции записи и чтения отличаются от операции load/store? Я всегда думал что это одно и тоже, но сейчас немного запутался в понятиях.

Запутался посмотрев на пример реализации spinlock на стандартынх атомиках

```
struct tas_lock {
  std::atomic<bool> lock_ = {false};

  void lock() { while(lock_.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire)); }

  void unlock() { lock_.store(false, std::memory_order_release); }
};
```

вот в чем состоит путаница, в документации написано

> memory_order_acquire  A load operation with this memory order performs
> the acquire operation on the affected memory location: no reads or
> writes in the current thread can be reordered before this load. All
> writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are
> visible in the current thread (see Release-Acquire ordering below)

тобишь, acquire - это операция загрузки (в моем понимании чтения), которая гарантирует атомарность и то что любые операции записи чтения не будут переупорядочены до нее.

> memory_order_release  A store operation with this memory order performs
> the release operation: no reads or writes in the current thread can be
> reordered after this store. All writes in the current thread are
> visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable (see
> Release-Acquire ordering below) and writes that carry a dependency
> into the atomic variable become visible in other threads that consume
> the same atomic (see Release-Consume ordering below).

операция освобождения гарантирующая что никакие операции записи чтения не могут быть переупорядочены после нее.

Но в примере выше используется операция записи с гарантией asquire (в моем понимании, обмен - это чтение + запись)

```
while(lock_.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire));
```

Учитывая вышеописанное, понятия загрузки/освобождения и чтения/записи - это не одно и тоже, чем они различаются?

PS: так же в заблуждение вводит формулировка из документации, описывающий std::atomic_flag

> std::atomic_flag is an atomic boolean type. Unlike all specializations
> of std::atomic, it is guaranteed to be lock-free. Unlike
> std::atomic, std::atomic_flag does not provide load or store
> operations.

тут написано что atomic_flag не обеспечивает load/store операций, не очень понятно что это значит, когда в примере той же документации описан похожий спин лок, использующий гарантии asq/relise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Чем атомарные операции записи и чтения отличаются от операции load/store?

Ничем, это одно и то же.

> Но в примере выше используется операция записи с гарантией asquire

`.exchange()` - это не просто запись, это одновременно и чтение и запись ("read-modify-write operation").

Они могут использовать любой порядок: хоть, `release`, хоть `acquire`, хоть одновременно `acq_rel`.

> тут написано что atomic_flag не обеспечивает load/store операций

У него буквально нет методов `.load()` и `.store()`, вместо них что-то более мутное.

В C++20 добавился `.test()`, который по сути заменяет `.load()`, но вот вместо `.store()` только `.clear()` (который как `.store(false)`), и `.test_and_set()` (который как `.exchange(true)`).